How to ask a prompt question with a section of dataframe available to view
I am trying to write a prompt question in my code but would like to know if its possible to insert a snippet of data frame within the question/question box. I currently am using winDialogString() but am open to other ideas to make this possible. My current question is as follows;
df
id   name
1    john
2    james
3    steve
4    david

winDialogString("Please add a id","")

What I'm looking to do is add the data frame into the question so it is visible when checking the id. This is mainly so I can have the question prompt and df snippet in one when answering the question as there is something to refer too. (It doesn't have to be using winDialogString())

I think you'd be better off firing up a small Shiny app in your code, especially if you're working in RMarkdown.  But without a min imal reproducible  example....

This is an improvisation for what you are looking for:
register <- \(){
  
  df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:4,
    name = c("john","james","steve","david")
  )
  
  assign("person",readline("What is your name?:"))
  
  id <- subset(df,name == person)[[1]]
  
  return(paste(glue::glue(person,"'s"),"id is",id))
  
}

register()

What is your name?:john
[1] "john's id is 1"

The above code creates a data frame within a function that is then filtered using the subset() function based on a supplied value in the name column of the data frame.
So if you want to get the id of the person named "john", run the application, answer the question and you will get a message printed in your console.
This interactivity is made possible by the readline() function.
Hope this helps!
